# Generic abstract class filter in NHibernate AutoMap for component

Tags: c#, generics, nhibernate

I'm overriding `IsComponent` method of NHibernate's `DefaultAutomappingConfiguration` to specify that my component is every class that implements a generic abstract class but don't find how.

this is the base class of my `ValueObject`:

```
public abstract class ValueObject<T> : IEquatable<T> where T : class
```

I want to write something similar to:

```
public override bool IsComponent(Type type)
    {
        return type.BaseType == ValueObject<T> where T : class;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this condition:

```
type.BaseType.IsGenericType && type.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ValueObject<>)
```

That condition will match every type where base type is generic and its open-generic version is `ValueObject<T>`